# HTML only way to add a new query string to an existing one

Tags: html, query-string

If I start out on the page `example.com/example` and click and a link `<a href="?this">`, I get sent to `example.com/example?this`. But if I start out on `example.com/example?that` and click `<a href="?this">`, `?this` overwrites `?that` and I get sent to `example.com/example?this`.

Is there an HTML only (no javascript) way to have a link send me to `example.com/example?this&that` if I start out on `example.com/example?that` but send me to `example.com/example?this` if I start out on `example.com/example`?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. You will have to use a server-side language or JavaScript to build the hrefs in order to achieve this.

The better question is whether it is really a good idea to heavily rely on query parameters or whether you could make use of some .htaccess URL rewriting (that is internally mapped to query parameters, but they will always be available as long as the URL structure is intact). You could also make use of session storage in your server-side language.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for your answer. P.S. I'm not relying on them by choice. It's just a case where I'm working with what's available to me, i.e. It's not my site, just another site where I'm able to post HTML content but no javascript.

Answer (score 0):

No, html urls are relative to the path you are currently on, not including query strings. You will need javascript.